# SELECT NOT EXIST in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I want to execute this sql query through hibernate in the persistence layer and use this queries result for updating book. I have used this query in Mysql workbench and it worked fine. The query is as follows:

```
"SELECT NOT EXISTS("+
                        "SELECT delivery_request_id FROM delivery_request WHERE book_id= "+book.getBookId()+" AND status LIKE 'PENDING')"+
                        "AND"+
                        "(SELECT NOT EXISTS(SELECT return_request_id FROM return_request rr WHERE rr.book_id="+book.getBookId()+" AND rr.delivery_request_id NOT IN ("+
                        "SELECT dr.delivery_request_id FROM delivery_request dr WHERE dr.book_id= "+book.getBookId()+" AND dr.status LIKE 'CLOSED')))"+   
                        "AND"+
                        "(SELECT NOT EXISTS"+
                        "(SELECT return_request_id FROM return_request WHERE book_id= "+book.getBookId()+" AND (status LIKE 'PENDING' OR status LIKE 'CANCELLED') ))"
```

I tried `session.createSQLQuery()` but don't know what to use for executing this.So how can this query be executed.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to run it.
Here is the code:

```
BigInteger result = (BigInteger) localSession.createSQLQuery("SELECT NOT EXISTS("+
                    "SELECT delivery_request_id FROM delivery_request WHERE book_id= "+book.getBookId()+" AND status LIKE 'PENDING')"+
                    "AND"+
                    "(SELECT NOT EXISTS(SELECT return_request_id FROM return_request rr WHERE rr.book_id="+book.getBookId()+" AND rr.delivery_request_id NOT IN ("+
                    "SELECT dr.delivery_request_id FROM delivery_request dr WHERE dr.book_id= "+book.getBookId()+" AND dr.status LIKE 'CLOSED')))"+   
                    "AND"+
                    "(SELECT NOT EXISTS"+
                    "(SELECT return_request_id FROM return_request WHERE book_id= "+book.getBookId()+" AND (status LIKE 'PENDING' OR status LIKE 'CANCELLED') ))").uniqueResult();
boolean exists = result.signum()>0;
```

Now I can use exists value for furthur operation.